# Andreev reflection (electron reflected as a hole) : Metal-Superconductor at $T=0$

Tags: superconductivity

I don't understand how it is possible to have Andreev reflection at $T=0$ if the particles conserve their energies.

Imagine I have a metal and a superconductor.

I have $\epsilon_k=E_k-E_F^{N}$ and $-E_F^{N}\leq\epsilon_k\leq0$ for the electron of the metal where $E_F^{N}$ is its Fermy energy and $E_k=\frac{h^2k^2}{2m}$.

The holes have $-\epsilon_k$ energies, so their energy will be : $ 0\leq-\epsilon_k\leq E_F^{N}$

Now, I put a generator of tension between my superconductor and my metal, such as the metal is now at the potential $V$. This will "translate" my energy curves of the metal of an energy $+eV$.

Then, I have the following curves :

[image]

My question is : how is it possible at $T=0$ to have an electron reflected as a hole at the same energy in the metal. Indeed holes and electrons **don't** have the same energies at $T=0$.

Comment: What is $T$ to begin with ? Holes and electrons have no clear meaning in a superconductor. On the band structure plot (or what seems to be that, since you did not define what you plot ...) bottom right of the picture, you can trace a horizontal line at some energy with intersect the band four times. Then the positive slope intersections are called *electron branches* and the negative slope intersections are called *hole branches*.

Comment: The Andreev reflection associates (around one bottom of the band) an incident electron (moving from left to right say) to an emitted hole) moving from right to left say).